# $lt 100 of $sum using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to calculate the total of each state using $sum.  To then only display the states that are less than 100 using $lt.

Working total of each sum:

```
 db.zipcode.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$state", count_of_cities:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Attempt at displaying sum less than 100:

```
 db.zipcode.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$state"}, less_than:{$cond:{if:{$lt:[$sum:1,100]}}}}])
```

Sample collection:

```
 { "_id" : "01001", "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA" }
 { "_id" : "05042", "city" : "RYEGATE", "loc" : [ -72.072669, 44.193453 ], "pop" : 328, "state" : "VT" }
 { "_id" : "05043", "city" : "EAST THETFORD", "loc" : [ -72.19668, 43.825757 ], "pop" : 657, "state" : "VT" }
 { "_id" : "08052", "city" : "MAPLE SHADE", "loc" : [ -74.99464399999999, 39.951085 ], "pop" : 19365, "state" : "NJ" }
```

The whole collection is available on the official MongoDB website : http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json

Comment: could you provide sample document of your zipcode collection?

Comment: Just edited it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform :

- 1 `$group` for summing the cities into `count_of_cities`
- 1 `$match` to filter your amount value

Query is :

```
db.zipcode.aggregate([{
    $group: { _id: "$state", count_of_cities: { $sum: 1 } }
}, {
    $match: {
        count_of_cities: { $lt: 100 }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Great, you can mark the question as solved if it's good for you